# How to iterate on array of pointers to void

Tags: c, arrays, void-pointers

I want to do a function that is able of shift array elements but the arrays can be of ints or of a struct defined by me. How do I iterate on pointers to void arrays?

This is my code so far for this example I'm using Ints but I plan to use the same function with other data types:

```
void shift(const void *source, int pos, int lenght){

    memmove(&source[pos], &source[pos+1], sizeof(int)*(lenght-pos-1) );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    shift(a, 3, 10);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "void arrays"? Arrays which do not hold any values?

Comment: In C the `[..]` operator acts as a *dereference*. You cannot dereference a `void` type. Your only real option is to cast everything to `char*` along with the `sizeof (your_type)` and adjust the indexing as required.

Comment: By void arrays I meant an array whose elements as void*

Comment: If you had an array of `void *` you would have a variable of type `void **`, but that's not what you have.  You need to show exactly how this function is called.  Please update your question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do to make this work across arbitrary data types is to pass the size of the data as well. This will let you calculate the offset. For example,

```
void shift(void *source, size_t size, int pos, int length){
    int src_offset =  pos * size;
    int dst_offset = (pos + 1) * size;
    memmove(source + src_offset, source + dst_offset, size*(length-pos-1) );
}
```

Now you can use different data types like so

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // ints
    int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    shift(a, sizeof(int), 3, 10);

     // chars
    char b[10] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'};
    shift(b, sizeof(char), 3, 10);

     //etc...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I tried to run it on macOS and it works for the char array but no for the int array. For int array it gives `([0] = 33554433, [1] = 50331648, [2] = 67108864, [3] = 83886080, [4] = 100663296, [5] = 0, [6] = 0, [7] = 0, [8] = 0, [9] = 0)`. Also the compiler gives: warning: arithmetic on a pointer to void is a GNU extension